# Minitube not playing nor downloading: is it an Ubuntu-specific issue?

Tags: multimedia

The title says it all. I downloaded and installed Minitube from repositories. The program's unable to play or download any video.

Secretly though it did play one video the first time for the length of the video, but never afterwards.

So what could be the issue? Is it related to the installation on Ubuntu? Am I missing something?

Comment: What version do you have?

Comment: current version is 1.3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A fix for youtube as been released a few days ago

- [MiniTube update story at OMGUbuntu](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2011/08/minitube-updated-youtube-fix/)
- [Minitube 1.5 to the Rescue](http://flavio.tordini.org/minitube-1-5-to-the-rescue)

To update to the latest version you will need to add Ferramosca Roberto's PPA

`ppa:ferramroberto/minitube`

You can find a description of how to add this here

[What are PPAs and how to I use them](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4983/what-are-ppas-and-how-do-i-use-them)

Hope this helps

Ps. Flavio has a feed for his blog if you want to know of any updates Before OMGUbuntu :)

- [Flavio's Blog Feed](http://flavio.tordini.org/feed)